# Passing value to action method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a next view:

```
<form class="actionButtons">
   <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" min="1" max="99" value="1" style="width:35px;"/>
   @Html.ActionLink("+ Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Cart", new { productId = Model.ProductID, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)
</form>
```

and action method:

```
public RedirectResult AddToCart(Cart cart,int productId, string returnUrl)
{
   Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
   if (product != null) cart.AddItem(product, 1);
   return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

How pass quantity value to this action method?
Thanks

Comment: Are you navigating to that link, or trying to post the form to that link?

Comment: Action link renders to link to /Cart/AddToCart and passes GET params productId and returnUrl when follow this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new { productId = Model.ProductID, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }))
{
    <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" min="1" max="99" value="1" style="width:35px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.BeginForm` that will submit all data to your AddToCart action. Also add link that will submit form.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript like JQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       var $qty = $("#Quantity");
       var $form = $qty.closest("form");
       var $link = $form.find("a");
       $link.click(function(e) {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.attr("href", $this.attr("href") + "&qty=" $qty.val());
       });
    });
 </script>
```